# Is there some way that I can cast or change a definition for an object with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript variable:

```
var home.modal.data;
```

In the content screen it contains:

```
home.modal.data.contentStatusId: number;
home.modal.data.contentTypeId: number;
```

In the exam screen it contains:

```
home.modal.data.examId: number;
home.modal.data.examStatusId: number;
```

I was considering an interface like this:

```
interface IModalData {
    contentStatusId: any;
    contentTypeId: any;
    current: any;
    examId: any;
    examStatusId: any;
}
```

But I think this is the wrong way to go about it and it is giving me other problems as I need to define properties that are not used.

Is there some other way that I could declare what the composition of home.modal.data is for each screen? I am sorry if this question sounds confusing but I did see some way 
of doing something like this with the `<>` bracket syntax but now I cannot find any examples.

I know one way is just for me to declare:

```
var home.modal.data: any
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this work for you

First define the following interfaces:

```
interface IExamData{
    examId: number;
    examStatusId: number;
}


interface IContentData{
    contentStatusId: number;
    contentTypeId: number
}
```

Now, whenever you need to access the data for either exam screen or content screen, depending on which context you can cast as follows:

When in exam screen:

```
var examData = <IExamData>home.modal.data;
examData.examId = 666;
examData.examStatusId = 777;
```

When in content screen:

```
var contentData = <IContentData>home.modal.data;
contentData.contenStatusId = 666;
contentData.contentTypeId = 777;
```

Answer (score 0):

The <> bracket syntax has a direct relation with generics.

See this document on [generics and typescript](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Generics%20in%20TypeScript)

Comment: I checked out the link but I am sorry I cannot understand how I can apply the generics to my problem.